# Any way to show/compare object references in watch window?

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging I sometimes find the need to compare object references in the watch window to see if two variables are actually referencing the same object.

With C++ and pointers this is easy, but is there any way of doing this with C# references?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uniquely Identifying Reference Types in the Debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251450/uniquely-identifying-reference-types-in-the-debugger)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is actually a built in feature for comparing objects in the Watch window that doesn't require you to call any functions directly. It's in the right click menu as "Make Object ID"

[image: Make Object ID]

It will mark the object with an ID, and then you can add a second object and mark it with an id as well. If those object are the same reference, then they will have the same ID. This allows you to see if/when they change as you are debugging.

Comment: Fantastic. This is much easier and closer to what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: The ID appears at the right hand end of the Value column. You may need to make the Value column wider to see it.

Answer (score 6):

```
object.ReferenceEquals(objA, objB)
```

Comment: Didn't realise you could call functions in the watch window! Thanks!