# When debugging, is there a way to tell if an object is a different instance?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When debugging, I was expecting two different classes to be using the same instance of an object. All of the properties were the same for these two objects, but they were two different instances. Is there a way to tell that in the VS debugger?

In order to tell for sure, I was able to add a field to the class:

```
private string someId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Then, when debugging, I could at least look at that field for each of the two instances. Is there a better way that wouldn't involve having to create this dummy ID field?

Comment: Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)

Comment: @PeterRitchie So how do you do this in the debugger? The objects, that need to be checked, are in two different classes.

Comment: Shift+F9, type in "Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)" and press Reevaluate or Add Watch.  Or just type "Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)" in the Name column in the  Watch window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uniquely Identifying Reference Types in the Debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251450/uniquely-identifying-reference-types-in-the-debugger)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When debugging, in the Locals window, right-click on the instance and select "Make Object ID".

This will add number that is unique for this instance which is displayed whenever you see this
instance in the debugger (in tool-tips as well as in the watch window).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see "Make object ID" when I right-click on the variable when debugging.

Comment: Got it! You have to do it in your Locals window: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx. Excellent tip! Thanks!

Comment: When you use this option, what happens when the object is disposed? I am debugging some thing related to EF DbContext and it seems that these objects stay in the Locals window, even though (I hope) they were already disposed...

Answer (score 5):

[Object.Equals Method (Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx)

Edit: To check reference equality use [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)

Edit 2: While Debugging, Go to debug menu, windows --> immediate window (intellisense should work here) and `?Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)`

Comment: That doesn't do it, since it virtual. It can be overridden by a derived class.

Comment: Use ReferenceEquals, not Equals.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if  (object)p1 == (object)p2; will achieve the same thing, but a little faster? I don't remember 100%.

Comment: +1 for the tip, but Wolfgang's answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, you can also compare pointers. If you have two objects `obj1` and `obj2`, you can check (e.g. in Watch Window) their addresses with: `&obj1` and `&obj2`.

Note that objects may be moved around by the .NET runtime, so two address checks of the same object separated with some code execution in between may result in different addresses.