# Asp.net core: Do creating a new instance of ILogger<Type> each request cost expensive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nlog

Recently I have been working on a project based on a template written by another group in my company. This project built with `asp.net core 2.2` and it uses `NLog` as a logging framework behind the `ILogger` registered in the `ILoggerFactory`.

I noticed an interesting point that any service depend on `ILogger<service> logger` gets a new instance of the `logger`. The service indeed is registered as `transient` so its creation per request seems normal, but as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901666/does-injecting-iloggert-create-a-new-logger-each-time) I expect that the `logger` will be the same (i.e. `singelton`) instance for all instances of this service.

I can't upload all the code seems it's big and private. But it seems that the relevant lines are those:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateBuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder<Startup>(args).UseUnityServiceProvider()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configurationBuilder) =>
            {
                //... 
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

                LoadExternalNLogConfigFile(hostingContext);
            })
            .UseNLog(); // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
```

And those:

```
private static void LoadExternalNLogConfigFile(WebHostBuilderContext hostingContext)
    {
        var isRunningInContainer = hostingContext.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER");

        var xmlNLogConfigFilenameWithEnvName =
            $"nlog.{(isRunningInContainer ? "Docker." : "")}{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.config";
        var xmlNLogConfigFilename = $"nlog.{(isRunningInContainer ? "Docker." : "")}config";
        try
        {
            hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureNLog(xmlNLogConfigFilenameWithEnvName);
        }
        catch
        {
            hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureNLog(xmlNLogConfigFilename);
        }
    }
```

In order to check the equality of the `logger` instance, I've used the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578895/when-debugging-is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-an-object-is-a-different-instance).

I've tested also the `Nlog` "Hello world" project, as guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679727/use-nlog-in-asp-net-core-application). The test shown that the logger instance is identical for each request.

**My question**: Do creation of a new `ILogger` instance per object request costs expensive? Should I have to look for solution for that issue, or is it a negligible problem?

Comment: "Is it a negligible problem" - only you can tell that by benchmarking your app, we have no idea what you are doing so it's impossible to really tell. Having said that, if this was an expensive operation, there would have been many complaints about it by now...

Comment: You can see in the source that [loggers are cached](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/LogFactory.cs#L851)

Comment: @DavidG I can't display the program. My question is, if you have application with many services (i.e. objects) depend on ILogger, and those services created each request with a new instance of ILogger - Does it may have a significant impact on my web application (when using NLog)?

Comment: @stuartd Thanks! This is what I looked for! If it cached, it may have less impact.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is yes: it would be expensive.

However, there would be no reason to do that. Any logging system will create loggers as singletons in the IoC container or recycle loggers for the category in the `ILoggerFactory` implementation. The main point is that this is not something you should worry about. Just configure your logging on startup, and then inject `ILogger<YourController>` into controllers and other services. The logging infrastructure will manage reuse of the logger for you with DI magic.