# VS 2015 debugging: how do I know whether 2 object variables have the same object reference?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, memory-address

how do I know during debugging whether `obj` and `obj2` reference the same object in the following code?

```
object obj = new object();
object obj2 = new object();
obj2 = obj;
```

In VS 2008 I could easily see that by looking in the watch window or locals window or on the value tooltip of the variable, because they all showed the object address, which was really useful (code sample is C++/CLI, but was tested in C# as well):

[image]

**But VS 2015 does not. How do I get that info here?**

Comment: I'm using GetHashCode() for that, 2 different instances usually gives different hashcodes, but it can be tricky.

Comment: @3615: unsafe. Instances may be different but contain same data.

Comment: All you have to do is use the standard mechanism for testing for reference equality (object identity). See marked duplicate for specifics. Use the immediate window to make the actual call, passing the two references you want to check.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That's even more laborious. I prefer the solution that I found myself and posted below. Also, the "duplicate" post is everything but a duplicate! If you want to mark my question as a duplicate, then use the link I gave in my answer!

Comment: _"use the link I gave in my answer!"_ -- I did. But your question is also a duplicate of the other: i.e. you want to know how to test if two references are equal. That's answered precisely by the first as well. If you have some additional criteria that causes you to believe that perfectly good answers aren't adequate, it's your responsibility to make that clear in your question. Nothing in your question suggests anything except a desire to make the determination of reference equality.

Comment: Just keep the Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory 1 debugging window handy.  It shows the address.

Comment: I understand your pain, I also wish it was easier to just immediately see the unique address of the object. So far the easiest way I've found is to just do "Add Watch" on all the objects I'm interested in inspecting, then adding the object ID's from the Watch menu.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching and testing I found
[Uniquely Identifying Reference Types in the Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251450/uniquely-identifying-reference-types-in-the-debugger)
which gives a good workaround by creating "object IDs". However, in my opinion this is just a workaround and I would prefer if I could see the required info instantly.

Comment: I don't understand how making an object ID is "a workaround". As soon as you make the object ID, you'll see the required info "instantly", just like you want. I note that the post you found even mentions that you can just call `object.ReferenceEquals()` in the immediate window, just like you'd do any time you want to test for reference equality in code. So there's that option too.