# In Visual Studio, can I set conditional breakpoints that can peek variables from another scope?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Look at this code:

```
void F1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        F2();
}

void F2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        F3();
}

void F3() {
    int a = 0; // break point here
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        a ++;
}
```

I want to put a break point at the line `int a = 0;` in `F3()`, but I only want to pause when `i==70` in `F1()` and `i==80` in `F2()`.

That means when I am in `F3()`'s scope, I have to peek `F2()`'s and `F1()`'s local variables. But in actual code, those two variables are not meant to be passed down.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: related, not necessarily a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4251470/1132334 (object id approach, object ids are valid in the condition box of a breakpoint)

Comment: What I usually do in such cases is to create a global variable for debugging.

Comment: You cant see out-of-scope variables as they do not exist in another scope.

Comment: @0___________ inside the program no, but I wouldn't be so sure about MSVC debugger, since it supports the so-called [ObjectID references](https://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/20/how-to-track-an-object-which-is-out-of-scope-while-debugging/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to change the code, the less interfering code that I can imagine is the following - without using the trick of the hits count of @Maaz.

It is based on using the current thread to "storage" the values.

```
void F1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
    {
        CallContext<Int32>.SetData("i-first", i);
        F2();
    }
}

void F2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
    {
        CallContext<Int32>.SetData("i-second", i);
        F3();
    }
}

void F3() {
    int a = 0; // break point here
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        a ++;
}

//Helper class for .Net Core.
//For .Net Framework you can use CallContext.LogicalSetData, CallContext.LogicalGetData
public static class CallContext<T>
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLocal<T>> state = 
         new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AsyncLocal<T>>();

    public static void SetData(string name, T data) =>
            state.GetOrAdd(name, _ => new AsyncLocal<T>()).Value = data;

    public static T GetData(string name) =>
            state.TryGetValue(name, out AsyncLocal<T> data) ? data.Value : default(T);
}
```

The conditional expression for the breakpoint is:

```
CallContext<Int32>.GetData("i-first") == 70 && CallContext<Int32>.GetData("i-second") == 80
```

Comment: This looks good. Adding some code is OK for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a counter that track the number of times the fonction F3() is called.

```
//track F3() call of times
private int times = 0;
void F3() {
    int a = 0; // break point if times == 70 || times == 80
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        a ++;    
    //add 1 call of times
    times++;
}
```

Comment: code only answer is cool. But perhaps you can add details and explanation. like : "_Maybe you_ want to add a counter that track the number of `times` the fonction `Foo()` is called. That way you may use that to track the number of execution of ... etc"

Comment: This is indeed a solution. But sometimes what we need is not about counting. For example, maybe the condition I need in `F1()` is `some_array[i] == "Tom"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a conditional breakpoint that does a hit test. Set it to hit the value `7081` and it should work.

F2() is called `70` times, and for each of those `70` times, F3() is called `100` times. So, for the 71st loop, i.e. F1()'s `i == 70`, and 81th sub loop, i.e F2()'s `i == 80`, a hit test for `70*100 + 81` should work.

Comment: Doesn't A get reset every time?  There is a scope issue.

Comment: Yes, `a` would. But, to stop at the exact line as the question suggested, this is what I thought of.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Follow below steps

1. Set the breakpoint on the line you want to debug
2. Right-click on the breakpoint
3. Select "Conditions", this will prompt you to the pop-up
4. Write the condition
5. Close and Debug.

Comment: how does this address the issue of out-of-scope variables?